# Django Page not found (404) while using Oauth library (log in with Linkedin)

Tags: python, django, oauth

I am using the Oauth Library to Log in with LinkedIn
but i am getting forllowing Error

```
Page not found (404)
```

and the page get landed to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
```

which i have not implemented and unable to understand how to redirect to other page
i am using

```
Django 1.8
Oauth 1.0
```

I am follwing this link

```
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api
```

and my INSTALLED_APPS is

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'rest_framework',
'snippet',
'api',
'UserProfile',
#created for linkedin tutorial
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
#    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
)
```

Can anyone would help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#when-i-attempt-to-login-i-run-into-a-404-on-accounts-profile):

> When I attempt to login I run into a 404 on /accounts/profile/
>
> When you end up here you have successfully logged in. However, you
>   will need to implement a view for this URL yourself, as whatever is to
>   be displayed here is project specific. You can also decide to redirect
>   elsewhere:
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Comment: I added a sample url                                                                                  /myprofile                                                                                                        and added this url in     "Default Accept Redirect URL:" in  Myapp (LinkedIn)                                          but Not Working

Comment: You need to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/myprofile'` in `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks Daniel It Worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn authorization needs a `redirect_url` declared in your `My Apps` tabs of LinkedIn. When you create your authorization url with all the parameters that you need to specify LinkedIn redirects back you to this callback url with an `authorization_code` and `state`.

For example let us assume your parameters for the GET request on the linkedin authorization url is `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization`

```
import urllib

parameters = {
    'response_type' : 'code',
    'client_id' : '<Your Client Id>',
    'redirect_uri' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/'
    'state' : 'Some String',
    'scope' : r_emailaddress
}

encoded_parameters = urllib.urlencode(parameters)

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization' + '?' + encoded_parameters
```

After the authentication with linkedin page you will be redirected back to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/`. So just make sure that this url has been declared in your django app.

Comment: what url did you add in your my apps.? Complete url please.

Comment: Thanks Arpit  for helping me. I got the answer :P